# Points in CIE Lab color space

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color, conversion

The following points are Lab values (CIELAB color space)

`points={{46.76, 34.51, 17.08}, {43.51, 34.83, 15.7}, {45.49, 32.92, 15.24}}`

what I would like to do is a) represent them in 3D b) give each point the color it represents and c) label each point with a text, let us say `{"one","two","three"}`.
My starting point is an adaptation from the documentation:

`Graphics3D[{LABColor[#], Sphere[#, .2]} & /@ points, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"L", "a", "b"}, BoxRatios -> Automatic]`

However, I do not get the colors right.
thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't you need divide points by 255?

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci where does 255 come from? Shouldn't it be 100? (I am not sure but that is what documentation suggests).

Comment: @Kuba 255 for `RGBColor` After I posted my answer I started reading documentation it seems you are right.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LABColor.html) you need to divide values by `100`

```
points = {{46.76, 34.51, 17.08}, {43.51, 34.83, 15.7}, {45.49, 32.92, 
        15.24}};
    Graphics3D[{LABColor[#/100], Sphere[#, 0.2]} & /@ points, 
     Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"L", "a", "b"}]
```

[image]

According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099063/what-are-the-ranges-of-coordinates-in-the-cielab-color-space) formula for converting to color is

```
points ={{46.76, 34.51, 17.08}, {43.51, 34.83, 15.7}, {45.49, 32.92, 15.24}};
    {L, a, b} = Transpose@points;
{L = L/100, a = (a + 86.185)/184.439, b = (b + 107.863)/202.345};
pts = Transpose@{L, a, b};
Graphics3D[{LABColor[#], Sphere[#, 0.005]} & /@ pts, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"L", "a", "b"}]
```

[image]

Or this kind of converting

```
{L, a, b} = Transpose@points;
{L = L/100, a = (a + 128)/255, b = (b + 128)/255};
pts = Transpose@{L, a, b};
Graphics3D[{LABColor[#], Sphere[#, 0.005]} & /@ pts, Axes -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"L", "a", "b"}]
```

[image]

Comment: indeed `points` contain CIELab values, so one should only divide by 100 for `LABColor`. Right? Why 100 for L and 255 for a and b?